# Why does the Notes app show on the lock screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, notes.app, screen-lock

The Notes app occasionally shows on my lock screen. I understand that apps can show on this screen based on my location (ex: my AT&T app shows when I'm near an AT&T store) but I don't know why Notes would do this -- so far, once in my office and a couple of times in my bedroom at home. Any ideas?

It began happening after my upgrade to 9.0.2 though not sure if this specific version is to blame.

**Update:** I've now had this happen multiple times *in airplane mode* so I suspect this behavior may have nothing to do with my location.

Comment: The only ways I'm aware that this could happen are either location-specific suggestions (someone next door always opens Notes when they get home, for example) or Handoff (you have Notes open on your Mac). Or an iBeacon, but that's obviously not relevant here!

Comment: No Macs at home. And I don't even use Notes that often - maybe once or twice a week.

Comment: Only thing I can think of, then, is that your neighbors and coworkers use Notes a lot... But we'll see if someone else has another idea.

Answer (score 1):

Handoff is why the notes app shows up on my lock screen.

You could try disabling that entirely or be sure that no other device is communicating with your device over bluetooth or WiFi.

If you look at the text in the handoff settings, suggested apps can also be shown based on usage patterns. If you open notes every night at 7 pm, eventually the OS will suggest notes at that time based on inference. Since this intelligence was introduced with iOS nine, it would take a while for the OS to learn your habits so having it appear coincidental  with the 9.0.2 update seems plausible.

Comment: Good point. But in my case, Handoff already was disabled

Comment: @Keith it's more likely the "intelligent" pattern matching, but even if you see the handoff toggle off - it could be a bug :)